# How can I set the position of a IMFREEHAND handles in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, roi

I save a given position array and handle object defined by IMFREEHAND. 
After loading this data back to workspace I want to set this IMFREEHAND object again to the specified position analogous to i.e. IMRECT where I can set the position via parameter. 
I still found nothing like this. Has anyone an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use patch to set the position of object again

Example:

```
patch(Position_X ,Position_Y,1);
```

Comment: This puts a patch on the image but doesn't move the position of the actual `imfreehand` object.

Comment: To move Object from actual Position You can use impoly(gca,Pos) instead of patch